# How can you create multiple image buttons and have them work on all monitor resolutions?

Tags: css, image, button, resolution, monitor

Okay, so this is what I currently have for my webpage:
j sfiddle(dot)net/gTF9y/4/

Which is just one single image, with css code that makes it so that one image adjusts to different monitor resolutions.

What I want to do is have the exact same look of the webpage right now, but have there be 12 individual images in the same position rather than 1 big image, so that I can make those images "buttons" essentially that can be clicked to go to a different webpages.

I want to retain the image-adjusting-to-different-monitor-resolutions functionality though.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Instead of deleting the question, why not post as an answer _how_ you solved the issue? You might help somebody and you could get some reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create 3x3 grid of images using css.

http://jsfiddle.net/gTF9y/1/

```
.block { width:33.33333%; float:left; display:block; }
.block img {display:block; max-width:100%; width:100%; }
```

If you really want to warp the images when the page loads you can use jQuery to set the images to 1/3 the window height and width. Throw in a .resize() and it responds to changes in the browser after it's loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/gTF9y/3/

Comment: For the css version you'd change the 33% to 25%.

For the jQuery version change the winWidth / 3 to winWidth / 4.
http://jsfiddle.net/gTF9y/4/

Comment: So here's an updated version to remove all the spacing you were dealing with. http://jsfiddle.net/gTF9y/6/ When you move this to local version you need to include the js library [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) The source code you shared above has an incorrect html doccument setup. You aren't using a doc tag and your <head> should be above your <body>. Here's a good place to see what a html page should look like.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Comment: make sure you include the * { margin:0;padding:0; } to reset the body's margins. Also if you're looking at the result version of the fiddle the header they add will throw this off. Send a link to the hosted version of what you have if it's still not working.

Comment: K so your problem is where you put the javascript. When you load a page it loads content from top to bottom. When it hit's a js file it stops and executes it then continues. By having the script in the head it executes it before the content exists so it does nothing.

Move it to the bottom of the body. http://cl.ly/image/1I2Y012P131L

You also need to add a doctype to prevent browser problems.

Comment: The lines are likely just part of the resizing. You can also see them when you resize the browser. You could add a background color that would show up instead of the white.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I've divided a page into a 4x3 grid:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
        <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
        <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
html, body
{
    height: 99%;
    margin: 0;
}

div
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 33%;
    width: 25%;
}

div img
{
    height: 100;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Producing this:

[image]

Now all you need to do is add `<img src="something.png">` inside each `<div></div>`.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsdAr/7/show/) ([edit](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsdAr/7/)) with all images added.